# Windows server 2012 Essential R2 trial activation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, activation

I've installed Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2 on my server.
Then I've bought an OEM licence to add on this server.

I've tried to convert my trial to "full licenced" with my key, but the system always refuse my key :(

I've seen on Microsoft Web site that WS2012 Essentials trial can be converted to full version with the `slmgr.vbs` script, but it also refuses it !

I've also read somewhere that the server can't be a Domain Controller to be activated, but it seems that we can't remove the DC role on WS2012 Essentials R2 ?

Do someone have a trick ?

Regards

Edit : This is not a question about licensing, but a question about Activating a licence that I already own : The procedure given by microsoft gives me troubles, I ask for help about commands to make my server accepting my licence.

Comment: Try `Dism /Online /Get-TargetEditions` to see what your server thinks it can upgrade to.  Also, including the actual commands you run without the key and the error output would help the experts here answer the question.

Comment: GetTargetEditions gives "ServerStandard". What seems to be strange, is that Get-GurrentEdition gives "ServerSolutions"

Answer (score 0):

A OEM is sold with a new server. Legally you can't add an OEM license after X time to a server.

Having told that;  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574204.aspx

> From an elevated command prompt, determine the current edition name
>   with the command DISM /online /Get-CurrentEdition. Make note of the
>   edition ID, an abbreviated form of the edition name. Then run DISM
>   /online /Set-Edition:
>   /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula, providing the
>   edition ID and a retail product key. The server will restart twice.

Comment: The licence has been purchased with the server (both on amazon). Amazon sent me a bad package (english instead of French edition), so I had to go on with a trial since the server was needed by my client.

Comment: I've tried several commandes : the "Get-CurrentEdition" returns "ServerSolution", but the "Get-TargetEditions" gives "ServerStandard". When I run "DISM /online /Set-Edition:ServerSolution /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula", the error says that my edition cannot be activated to this edition (with error 50). When I run the same command with "ServerStandard", the error is different, and says that my key doesn't correspond to the target edition... (error 0x8a010001)

Comment: The link above from Microsoft says that Essentials editions must be activated by slmgr.vbs tool, and seems to only refer to Essentials "Non R2" versions...

Comment: @LudovicLemarinel In my first edit I wanted to wrote that you can't update a trial to OEM, as it was my experience, but I removed the text as in the MS's link they tell it's possible, but I now doubth it..

Comment: @LudovicLemarinel With slmgr.vbs, tried to run it that way ? slmgr.vbs -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

Comment: Yes I did, and it did returned an error : "An error happened on a computer running a non-core edition of Windows. Run slui.exe 0x2a 0C004E016 to get error text". (It might be different in real-english, since I've translated it by myself !). When I run the slui.exe with given parameter, it just says that an error happened, and that perhaps calling microsoft by phone might help !